# Insert string in string

Tags: c#, string

I'm having troubles insert a substring in a string
what I want is to inject `"/thumbs"` into a stringpath

```
/media/pictures/image1.jpg
```

I want to inject /thumbs/ into the last part of the path like this:

```
/media/pictures/thumbs/image1.jpg
```

Is it possible with linq?

Comment: Why would you use linq and not just the String Insert method?

Comment: Why would you use link and not just the nice `Path` utility class meant to help do stuff exactly like this? `string pathWithThumbs = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path), "thumbs"), Path.GetFileName(path));`

Comment: simple check for the last / (or first from the end) and then insert /thumbs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class, preferably in your own utility method or as an extension method.

```
string pathWithThumbs = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path), "thumbs"), Path.GetFileName(path));
```

Linq seems to be out of place here; you're not really querying collections. Plus, the `Path` class handles most of the slashes and corner cases for you automatically.

EDIT: As @juharr pointed out, as of 4.0 there's a handy overload making it even simpler:

```
string pathWithThumbs = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path), "thumbs", Path.GetFileName(path));
```

EDITx2: Hrrrm, as @DiskJunky points out, this Path usage will actually swap your forward slashes for backslashes, so just throw a `Replace("\\", "/")` call in there.

Comment: `Path.Combine` will now take a param array so you don't need to nest them.  I think that was added in .Net 4.0.

Comment: @juharr Thanks! It's been a long time since I've had to dive into using `Path` directly; very nice overload!

Comment: The result of your solution replaces the "/" with "\" - you need to complete it with a Replace() call at the end of the chain

Comment: @DiskJunky +1 Thanks for picking up on that.

Answer (score 4):

For something like path manipulation, it's best to use the `System.IO` namespace, specifically the `Path` object. You can do something like;

```
string path = "/media/pictures/image1.jpg";
string newPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path), "thumbs", Path.GetFileName(path)).Replace(@"\", "/");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, you get the index of the last forward slash and insert the additional string at that point.

Unsure as to why the downvote, but I assure it works.

```
string original = "/media/pictures/image1.jpg";
string insert = "thumbs/";
string combined = original.Insert(original.LastIndexOf("/") + 1, insert);
```

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I assume it's the "you should use `Path` methods instead of `string` methods" argument.

Comment: Most likely, but seems a little bit out of the way for such a simple operation IMO. `string.Insert` exists for a reason ;)

Comment: Yeah, and I'm not sure the Path methods would keep the slashes going the correct way / vs \

Comment: It seems silly to use `Path.Combine` just to replace the slashes afterwards. `string.Insert` is easier to read as well, no need to over-code it really.

Comment: @AdamKDean, well not in production code. The Path object is a little more versitile and something like this would possibly be put into a common library. A bit of a stretch perhaps but a job worth doing... :-) That said, I *do* like your approach - neat and to the point!

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible with linq?

You don't need to use *Linq* for this process. You can use **[String.Insert()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx)** method;

> Returns a new string in which a specified string is inserted at a
>   specified index position in this instance.

```
string s = "/media/pictures/image1.jpg";
string result = s.Insert(s.LastIndexOf('/'), "/thumbs");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output;

```
/media/pictures/thumbs/image1.jpg
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://ideone.com/6aPDoB)**.

Comment: That will give /media/pictures/thumbs//image1.jpg, you need to remove one of the slashes.

Answer (score 1):

I would use System.IO class called `Path`.

Here is the long(er) version for demonstration purposes only:

```
string pathToImage = "/media/pictures/image1.jpg";

string dirName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToImage);
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(pathToImage);
string thumbImage = System.IO.Path.Combine(dirName, "thumb", fileName);

Debug.WriteLine("dirName: " + dirName);
Debug.WriteLine("fileName: " + fileName);
Debug.WriteLine("thumbImage: " + thumbImage);
```

Here is a one-liner:

```
Debug.WriteLine("ShortHand: " + Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToImage), "thumb", Path.GetFileName(pathToImage)));
```

I get the following output:

```
dirName: \media\pictures
fileName: image1.jpg
thumbImage: \media\pictures\thumb\image1.jpg

ShortHand: \media\pictures\thumb\image1.jpg
```